# See own rejected edit requests

Tags: support, edits, statistics

**Is there a way of seeing my rejected edit requests.**

I do primarily edit on so as you can see here:

[image: Hille had 417 edit suggestions approved, and 51 edit suggestions rejected]

I want to improve my edits, but I can't find the newer rejected ones out of my total 468 edit suggestions
as most of the rejected ones are pretty old (*the quote on the first 3 pages are 1 rejection out of 20-30*).

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45755/my-rejected-edits

Comment: cross site dupe https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85193/how-can-i-see-all-my-rejected-edits

Comment: Your edit comments could be more descriptive. "General revision" doesn't tell much, if anything.

Comment: What should I type if I have changed nearly everything from grammar up to complete format changes @yivi

Comment: I think you should try to describe the changes, properly. Also, maybe you could try to save your suggested edits for posts that are higher quality than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19854749) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19852724). There is nothing to gain in these edits, IMO.